# Using a column in a function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
library(MASS)
data(cars)
```

What I want to do is pull all cars that have a dist of 20. I know I can do that using subset:

```
subset(cars,dist == 20)
```

But when I try to make a function that does the same thing, I keep getting errors. Here is what I tried:

```
pracfunc = function(dfo,colo){
lo = subset(dfo, colo == 20)
return(lo)}
```

and then

```
pracfunc(cars, "dist")
```

but I keep getting errors. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It seems so simple. I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: the warning under `?subset`

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what the error is.

Comment: From `?subset`: `"Warning: This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pracfunc <- function(dfo,colo){ dfo[dfo[[colo]] == 20, ] }

> identical(subset(cars,dist == 20), pracfunc(cars, 'dist'))
[1] TRUE
```